# Sharing Functions between two Angular js Controllers

Tags: angularjs, angular-strap

I have one requirement. I am using Angularstrap Modal for Modal Dialogue(User's Terms and Condition).

On this modal Dialogue Two buttons are there "Agree" and "Don't Agree".

I have two links. on clicking on each links different views are opened.Both views are associated with different controller.
And My requirement is like,I need to open Terms Dialogue whenever new user comes and that needs to open on click event of both link.
Currently I have to write modal code in each controller.(Same function to open modal and for the modal's buttons)

Now,I want to generalize the code for the modal and modal's button.I want to write once and I want to use that code whenever I need to open (any) Modal

What can be the Approach or is it possible?

Comment: You want a service most likely.  If you want to re-use some DOM manipulation code then you probably want a directive.

Answer (score 0):

This is skeleton pseudo code for my dialog service:

```
//modal container is the template with backdrop 
//and other modal elements (title, body, buttons, close button)
loadContainerTemplate() 
//the actual html content for the modal body
.then(loadDialogTemplate)
.then(init);

function init() {
  //append container to body
  //append dialog template to modal body
  //create new scope for the modal
  //set up buttons, title, width, etc.
  //listen for ESC keypress
  //initialize modal controller if needed
  //prepare close function (destroy scope, remove dom, execute close callbacks, etc)
  //compile modal html against scope
}
```

My service would accept arguments such as modal template's url, title, width, buttons and their callbacks, parent scope etc. In your controller you would just call the dialog like this:

```
function($scope, Dialog) {
   Dialog({scope: $scope, templateUrl: 'path/to/modal/body', buttons: {
     'agree': agreeCallback,
     'disagree': disagreeCallback
   }, title: 'Modal title'});
}
```

Or you could go one step further and create TermsModalService that would abstract details like template, buttons, callbacks, title, etc and use the underlying Modal service to show the actual dialog. The Terms modal would be easily usable between all controllers with one-liner: `TermsDialogService.show();`